# UITableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath not working for the last row

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

At the last row of tableview, i have a text field which takes input and on done, it adds a text in the row and update the tableview. I need to scroll tableview to the last row when the keyboard shows up.

I have done two things to manage this, but it didn't work.

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [archiveTabelView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow  inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
    archiveTabelView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

It's not working, and if we call scrollToRowAtIndexPath after a delay it's even not working.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Make sure you have set the delegate and check with breakpoint is the method is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle the scrolling when the keyboard is shown, is to register your class as an observer to the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` or `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` depending when you want to move your content up and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` or `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` depending when you want to move your content down.

When one of these notification is sent in the notification object you can find the keyboard size, this size will allow you to move the content up/down or increase/decrease the `contentSize` properly.

Also be careful, if you call `resingFirstResponder` on a `UITextField` the hide notification will be sent.

Now in order to make your table view to scroll properly when the keyboard is shown/hide you will have to increase/decrease the `contentSize` of the tableView `UIScrollView` and  probably use `setContentOffset:animated:` instead of `scrollToRow`.

Comment: It worked, but wondering why is scrollToRow not working. Thanks though!

Comment: @NabeelThobani The scrollToRow will scroll until the row is visible. So if your row is visible (at the bottom) it won't scroll anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Setting animated to NO somehow worked for me. Not sure the exact reason behind this though.

```
[archiveTabelView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow  inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add more content size. and try to see that tableview frame is with in the content size.If you want you can inrease both frames.